# An annoying little square on Android devices in ionic3?

Tags: sass, ionic3

Recently I created an hybrid application developped with Ionic 3. I noted a little problem: sometimes a little square appears when open the side menu and close the side menu dots are visibe.initially not show any little square.

**Steps to reproduce:**

add Below css in app:

> scroll-content{
>         overflow-y: auto; }
>
> .scroll-content{ overflow-y: auto !important; }
>
> .content .scroll-content {
>       overflow-y: auto; }

Above solution are not working for me please tell me how to fix this issue?

Check below image 
[image]

Comment: does it also appear in chrome? if yes you can try to inspect the css and see what elements produce this. After that you can hide that element via css.

Comment: Sir in case of normal ionic serve not showing any dots in chrome browser.yes sir i tried with the css and override the overflow-x that is placed inside the scroll-content it is working for that time but after slide the side menu and the close in such case dots show again.

Comment: what u can also try is to use the chrome inspect feature with a debug version of the app and try to check the css via chrome inspect.

for me it looks like you are using a list and it has the list style decoration. You can try to disable it if you find the correct place with ul {list-style-type: none;}

Comment: @nosTa sir troed but not working for me

Comment: I would need a copy of the project to check it myself. Otherwise it is hard to tell where the issue is.

Comment: @nosTa: sir i have fixed above issue 1month before put below css in app.scss :
::-webkit-scrollbar, *::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}